# change css in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

developing a project in wordpress change wanted pictures of the odd cells in the list
i prove the next code but isn't works

```
 ul:nth-of-type(3n+1) li {
    padding: 0 0 0 14px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    background: url(images/widget-list.png) left 6px no-repeat; /*azul*/
    background-position: left 4px;
}

.widget ul:nth-child(3n+2) li {
    padding: 0 0 0 14px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    background: url(images/widget-list1.png) left 6px no-repeat; /*verde*/
    background-position: left 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:nth-child(odd)` to target odd elements.